# Help with Fun project: Easter Egg jQuery DJ

Tags: jquery, audio

I'm working on a redesign of my website, and would like to make a Easter Egg. On the site, I use circles a lot, and would like to let the user click on some of them, to trigger a loop/pattern like a beat or so. When pressing other circles a note is played. So you could actually play a simple tune, with a beat.

I've searched the web for similar solutions, but I can't seem to find any.

Can any of you guide me in the right direction, or help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be possible to create a simple flash movie, that will play certain notes controlled by javascript. Have a look at [SoundManager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager/) or [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/).

Comment: I would really like to do something without Flash, so it could work on iPads and iPhones as well.

Comment: Then you should do a combination of flash for non-HTML5 browsers and `<audio>` for mobile browsers.

Comment: Thank you. That will be my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can embed some hidden `audio` elements and `play()` them via JavaScript.

Comment: @Kenneth Correct. You could always provide a Flash fallback.

Comment: For Easter Egg stuff, I think it is all right to use the HTML5 audio tag. It won't work in IE (<9), but hey, it is just an Easter Egg :). Audio support: http://caniuse.com/#search=audio

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach... that builds on alex's suggestion.

I created a simple implementation with angular (you really should use this instead of jquery :) ...really!) that can be seen here:

In this solution, I did the following:

- drew a circle in a div with CSS
- wired up a click event to that circle that played a sound in a hidden
  audio element

Pretty simple!

http://jsfiddle.net/joshpierro/tw5cg2es/4/

html

```
<Body ng-app="circles">
    <div ng-controller="circleController">

        <h3>{{name}}</h3>
        click the circle to play the sound
        <br><br>
 <div class="circle" id="circle" ng-click="playSound()">
 </div>

   <audio controls id="sound" class="player">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>


</div>
</body>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('circles',[]);

app.controller('circleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.name = 'Circle App'; 


    $scope.playSound = function(){
        document.getElementById('sound').play();
    }

}]);
```

css

```
.circle{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```